# How to validate date type in POST payload with flask restplus?

Tags: python, post, flask, payload, flask-restplus

Consider the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
ns = api.namespace('ns')

payload = api.model('Payload', {
    'a_str': fields.String(required=True),
    'a_date': fields.Date(required=True)
})

@ns.route('/')
class AResource(Resource):

    @ns.expect(payload)
    def post(self):
        pass
```

If I POST `{"a_str": 0, "a_date": "2000-01-01"}` I get 400 as expected, 
because `a_str` is not a string.
However, when I POST `{"a_str": "str", "a_date": "asd"}` I don't get 400.
Here I would like to also get 400, because "asd" is not a common date format.

I looked into the `Date` class [doc](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/flask_restplus/fields.html) and
I see that there is a `format` and a `parse` method which should check whether the string is in a common date format.
However, they do not seem to be called here.

Is there another way how to do this?
Currently I am validating the date format by hand, but it seems that fask restplus should be able to do it for me.

Comment: Can you show `curl` request? in my case I don't see any 400 errors(`curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \
   "a_str": 0, \
   "a_date": "aa" \
 }' 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/ns/'`)

Comment: I just copy pasted your request. Get 400 because "a_str" is not a string (which is good, I would also like that behaviour for the date)

Comment: I stumbled upon this: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html. Im not using reqparse here, but may it be that all parsing and serialization is supposed to be done with marshmallow and not with the flask_restplus tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @andilabs mentions, it really weird to define expected payload twice. You can define expected payload by using only `RequestParser` as so:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields, reqparse, inputs

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
ns = api.namespace('ns')

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('a_str', type=str)
parser.add_argument('a_date', type=inputs.datetime_from_iso8601, required=True)


@ns.route('/')
class AResource(Resource):

    @ns.expect(parser)
    def get(self):

        try:  # Will raise an error if date can't be parsed.
            args = parser.parse_args()  # type `dict`
            return jsonify(args)
        except:  # `a_date` wasn't provided or it failed to parse arguments.
            return {}, 400


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Test by using `curl`:

```
$ curl -XGET -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"a_str": "Name", "a_date": "2012-01-01"}' 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/ns/'
{
  "a_date": "Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT", 
  "a_str": "Name"
}
```

Comment: this is strange, that you have to define it twice.. once with api.model and once with request parser.  why so?

Comment: I think `expect` is used in swagger documentation and the other one is used for parsing arguments. But I found example where you can define parser once, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @andilabs I've updated the answer. I hope this suits your needs. It's also better and simpler example

Comment: This solution worked for me. Despite I feel that the `api.model` syntax is a bit more succint code-wise, creating a `reqparse` instance allows for reuse for input validation and documentation. Besides it makes it easier to pass parameters to the swagger interface.
(Despite this, I don't know if it's better to maintain models in order to keep a clearer interface between the endpoints and the Domain Logic)

Answer (score 4):

To validate you can add parameter validate:

```
@ns.expect(payload, validate=True)
```

Here is the link to documentation:
https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#the-api-expect-decorator

Comment: so far so good, but it appears that it fails for certain cases :/\

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: `pip install isodate`

Step 2: `pip install strict-rfc3339`

Step 3:

```
from jsonschema import FormatChecker
api = Api(your_app,format_checker=FormatChecker(formats=("date-time",)))
```

Step 4:

```
@api.expect(your_fields, validate=True)
```

Reference:
Open Issue: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/204